# PHP. Strtotime. Странное поведение

Tags: php, дата

Всем доброго времени суток!

Написал ф-цию, которой на вход приходит определенная дата, и к ней прибавляются N дней(кол-во дней так же передается на вход.)
Т.к. на вход может передаться как "Y-m-d", так и timestamp,  я решил обработать такой вариант:

```
if (false !== strtotime($date)) {
    $date = strtotime($date);
}
```

Вот если на вход 1580446800("2020-01-31"), то strtotime возвращает false,
а вот если на вход передается 1359403200("2013-01-28"), то strtotime возвращает 38840756380.

В чем кроется сакральная идея, которой я не понимаю?

Comment: Вы уверены что точно на вход подаёте 2020-01-31? работает корректно. Может где в другой части кода какие-то проблемы

Comment: Подтверждаю вышесказанное. Всё прекрасно работает.

Comment: Какая версия php? Какая ос? 64/32?

Comment: win server 2008. 64

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/81476615c0126bd824fa8ce643f2ef3e51573acc   Вот пример

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в $date хранится уже timestamp

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php а где тут написано что `strtotime` принмает timestamp

Comment: @Naumov точно.
Проверку пришлось изменить на is_numeric